# Saving a newly created entity with default values from config file that are immutable for subsequent persists

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have a requirement, using Doctrine to save an entity with preset values that are populated from application configuration.

There are multiple applications, sharing same codebase, with different configurations.

My initial idea was to use a pre-persist listener, load config values and be done, but the problem is, these attributes should NOT be changed  after entity is created, even if the configuration file changes the original entity's configuration needs to stay as they were initially.  Even if entity is loaded in a form and resaved with other values changed, these specific initial applicatin settings should only be set on entity creation and kept for the entire lifecycle of the entiy as they were at the start.

I understand, it is possible to set the values on the entity with the setters of the entity, but since these entities are created at various places in the application my thought was that using a pre-persist hook would reduce code duplication.

Is there a way to detect if an entity is newly created, or another listener I could use? I skimmed through the documentation and did not see listeners specific to object creation.

I thought maybe on first pre-persist, some entity attributes such as "created" is possibly not set on first pre-persist called,  when object is created and persisted for the first time.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do, some way to set values on entity creation that is immutable over subsequent persists?

Comment: pre-persist sounds to be the event that you are looking for; it is triggered only in the initial insert. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events: "... It should be noted that this event is only triggered on initial persist of an entity (i.e. it does not trigger on future updates)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. Of course you can use the `prePersist` event as they pointed out in the docs

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

> prePersist - The prePersist event occurs for a given entity before the
>   respective EntityManager persist operation for that entity is
>   executed. It should be noted that this event is only triggered on
>   initial persist of an entity (i.e. it does not trigger on future
>   updates).

I would also add a constraint to the entity, that saving your entity with empty value for your desired fields is not possible. So it's ensured that there is no inconsistency.